# Trying to create a stored procedure that takes a parameter, and uses an if statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

run one stored procedure called QuerySchema that takes a parameter called "SelectedSchema." This procedure will use an IF statement to return data from the following views:

```
Parameter       View to Query
TABLES      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
COLUMNS     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
VIEWS       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
ROUTINES    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

^ that is what my assignment says.

Trying to get the basic layout for the code.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE QuerySchema(SelectedSchema VARCHAR(70))                                            
 IF SelectedSchema = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES                                                       
 THEN SELECT table_name, table_type, engine                                                          
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES                                                                      
 WHERE table_schema='dmccann';                                                                       
 END IF;                                                                                             
 //
```

ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' in field list

^ is the error I'm getting.

but, if I just use

```
 SELECT table_name, table_type, engine                                                          
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES                                                                      
 WHERE table_schema='dmccann';
 //
```

I get the desired result. Since, I'm only taking in one selection for the parameter at this time, I don't need an else statement, do I?

Comment: that was my fault at the beginning, I didn't copy/paste my code, I just typed it here and didn't proof read it. But, I figured it out. Thanks for the great response.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

```
  IF SelectedSchema = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

needed to be

```
  IF SelectedSchema = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
```